# Can I use SVCUTIL to create a Web Service reference for .NET 2.0 (i.e. NOT for a WCF Client)

Tags: wcf, service, wsdl

We have a WCF service exposing a `basicHTTPBinding` endpoint, but I need to consume it from a .NET 2.0 application.

We do have the WSDL files available.

Is there a way to use `SVCUTIL` to generate a web service reference which is compatible with .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't but you can use tool called wsdl.exe or Add Web Reference in Visual studio.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav - wsdl.exe works (although seems to miss the wildcard functionality that svcutil does i.e. svcutil ..\*.wsdl ..\*.xsd /language:C#)